# NSMutableArray - array pop equivalent

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray, foundation

If I want to pop the last item from my `NSMutableArray` would this be the most proper way?

```
id theObject = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:myMutableArray.count-1];
[myMutableArray removeLastObject];
```

I'm sure someone from SOF has a better way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Retain it, delete it, use it, release it.

```
id theObject = [[myMutableArray lastObject] retain];
[myMutableArray removeLastObject];
//use theObject....
[theObject release];
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no pop equivalent for `NSMutableArray` but I guess you could easily add a category to it for popping. Something like this perhaps:

**NSMutableArray+Queue.h**

```
@interface NSMutableArray (Queue)
-(id)pop;
@end
```

**NSMutableArray+Queue.m**

```
#import "NSMutableArray+Queue.h"

@implementation NSMutableArray (Queue)
-(id)pop{
    id obj = [[[self lastObject] retain] autorelease];
    [self removeLastObject];
    return obj;
}
@end
```

Then import it and use it like this:

```
#import "NSMutableArray+Queue.h"
...
id lastOne = [myArray pop];
```

Comment: Are you sure you the object it returns should be copied? I would expect to pop the same object off the stack that I put on it.

Comment: @Monolo Thanx man I have updated the answer (if anyone knows though how this could be done under ARC I would be interested).

Comment: Just get rid of the `retain` and `autorelease` messages. ARC should take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lastObject` to get the last object in the array.

That would save you a few keystrokes.

If you want to be able to call it with a single line of code, you can wrap it all in a function or a category on `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: removeLastObject in an NSMutableArray returns void